# I want to add multiple images into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm working on this feature in my project where I want to add three(3) images along side other details into my database row and I want this images to be in separate columns in one row.... So far below is my code. the  code is not working yet... The images and texts are not uploading to the database....
Please help me out guys. What am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Below is my code sample:

//THE PHP SECTION//

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'includes/config.php';

if (isset($_POST['post']) && isset($_POST['itemtype'])) {

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']);
    $itemtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['itemtype']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);
    $image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
    $image1_tmp_name = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
    $image2_tmp_name = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
    $image3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
    $image3_tmp_name = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['category']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);

    //image file directory
    $target1 = 'images/user_ads/'.basename($image1);
    $target2 = 'images/user_ads/'.basename($image2);
    $target3 = 'images/user_ads/'.basename($image3);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1_tmp_name'], $target1)) {

    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2_tmp_name'], $target2)) {

    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3_tmp_name'], $target3)) {

    }

    //insert into ost database
    $insert = "INSERT INTO products(Title,Product_Type,Description,Image1,Image2,Image3,Price,Category,Name,PostedDate)VALUES('$title','$itemtype','$description','$target1','$target2','$target3','$price','$category','$name',NOW())";
    $insertKwary = mysqli_query($link, $insert);

    if ($insertKwary) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-success'>Product Submitted</div>";
    }else{
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-success'>Product Not Submitted...Try again</div>";
    }
}

?>
```

//THE HTML SECTION//

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <?php if(isset($msg)) { echo $msg; } ?>
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="postAdForm" id="postAdForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Ad_title">Item Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control title" id="title" required=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="itemtype">Item Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="itemtype" id="itemtype">
                                <option>Sale</option>
                                <option>Request</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Item Description</label>
                            <textarea name="description" class="form-control description" id="description" rows="7" required=""></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">First Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image1" class="form-control image1" id="image1" required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Second Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image2" class="form-control image2" id="image2" required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Third Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image3" class="form-control image3" id="image3" required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Price</label>
                            <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price" id="price" required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="category">Item Category</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                                <option>Sale</option>
                                <option>Request</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control name" id="name" required="" readonly="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="post" class="btn btn-post post" id="post" value="POST AD" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

I've also attached an image of the error i'm getting..

[image of web page showing thee errors i get..error gotten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQAFY.png)

Comment: $_FILES['image1_tmp_name'] I believe is supposed to be $image1_tmp_name same for 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to these lines:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1_tmp_name'], $target1)) {
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2_tmp_name'], $target2)) {
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3_tmp_name'], $target3)) {
}
```

You're setting $image1_tmp_name, not $_FILES['image1_tmp_name'].

Try this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($image1_tmp_name, $target1)) {
}
if (move_uploaded_file($image2_tmp_name, $target2)) {
}
if (move_uploaded_file($image3_tmp_name, $target3)) {
}
```

Edit: Using `mysqli_error()` to print the error helped solve additional issues (Mentioned in comments)

Comment: ok... Thanks @dustytrash.... Thee errors are gone, thee images uploaded to the specified directory... but there's no data in my mysql table

Comment: @user3449184 Does the query result in an error? What datatype are those image columns by the way?

Comment: Yea it results in the error i specified "Product not submitted"....And for the images they're VARCHAR datatypes....... its not only the images that is not submitted to database, both the TITLE,DESC......e.t.c

Comment: You Can't use Varchar to store an image. Unless you're just storing the location? As for the error print $mysqli->error instead. E.G: `$msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-success'>" . $mysqli->error . "Product Not Submitted...Try again</div>";`

Comment: Hey bro @dustytrash... amma say a very BIIIG Thank ya..... You saved me.... I used the $mysqli_error() and it showed me that the Field Name that I'm sending to ain't thesame name i used in the TABLE..... I changed that nd BANG! iit work am so soo Greatful Bro....... Wanna ask ya for something.... can u dro ya Mobile No. maybe we did build this relationship more

Comment: Hey @dustytrash... What would you suggest I store the images with... ??

Comment: @user3449184 No problem! Glad you got it working! Tbh I wouldn't suggest storing images into a database. I'd suggest storing them on a Server, outside the database if possible. Maybe you could just store the image locations. BUT I'd suggest using a 'LONGBLOB' datatype if you are going to store them in a database.

Comment: Ok... Can ya kinda gimme code snippets on how to do it.... Or direct me to any tutorial that teaches that